# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta en eloquent? Relacionando otra tabla

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una duda con una consulta(Lo voy a resumir lo más que pueda)

Tengo una Tabla :  Users

| id | Nombre | ROLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Superman | Heroe |
| 2 | Thor | Heroe |
| 3 | Juan | Humano |
| 4 | José | Humano |

Otra tabla llamada Visitantes

En este caso  Superman Visito a José & juanpero solo Thor Visito a  Juan :(

| id | heroe_id | humano_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1_superman | 3_juan |
| 2 | 1_superman | 4_jose |
| 3 | 2_thor | 3_juan |

Ahora, Supongamos que por alguna extraña razón se puede Contactar a superman & thor

Tengo otra tabla llamada

Contactos

| id | from_id | destino_id | estado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1_juan | 1_superman | NULL |
| 1 | 1_juan | 2_thor | Rechazado |
| 1 | 2_jose | 1_thor | Aceptado |

La columna **Estado**

Me refiero a que yo voy hacer unas validaciones : ( Y otra persona tendrá la dicha de si el humano puede contactar a heroe)

1.- NULL ( Es que aún no se ha revisado esa solicitud)
2.- NO (Pues que no se podrá
3.- Aceptado(Pues le llego un correo al humano de donde podrán verse)

Ahora, Había estado haciendo una consulta  así

```
return Visit::with(['users'])
    ->where('humano_id',auth()->user()->id)
    ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
    ->paginate();
```

Antes de agregar la tabla de contactos, Solo podía visualizar los heroes que me hayan visitado( & eso estaba bien, pues el query que tengo arriba sirve bastante bien)

CONTACTAR(Pero necesito obtener el resultado de la tabla CONTACTOS

**EXPECTACTIVA DE RESULTADOS**

```
[
  {
    "Nombre": "Thor",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "contacto": {
      "id": 1,
      "from_id": 1,
      "destino_id": 2,
      "status": "Aceptado"
    }
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Superman",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "contacto": {
      "id": 1,
      "from_id": 1,
      "destino_id": 2,
      "status": "Rechazado"
    }
  }
]
```

Como estoy obteniendo actualmente los resultados

```
[
  {
    "Nombre": "Thor",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "contacto": []
  },
  {
    "Nombre": "Superman",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "contacto": []
  }
]
```

Contacto sale vació *pero no debería de salir *. Si ya le dí contactar a esa persona, puede que salga vació ese resultado, claro si aún no he hecho esa petición de querer contactar. :)

¿Qué estare haciendo mal en mi relaciones?

Porque  como es la misma tabla usuarios la tengo así

usuario 1-----M Visitas
usuario 1-----M contactos

Comment: `from_id` es la llave foránea que te vincula a contactos con users?

Comment: @BetaM si, de hecho  me faltó agregar un columna más. en la tabla de contacto(La persona que autoriza esa comunicación) Que va a la misma tabla de users 
entonces por así decirlo tengo apuntando la tabla de users 3 distintos tipo sde roles(por así decirlo hacía la tabla de Visitas)  no sé que esté haciendo mal :(

Comment: Para poderte ayudar procura proveernos por favor las relaciones definidas en los modelos involucrados, así como que agregues las columnas faltantes, de modo que podamos ayudar

Comment: sigues sin proveer la información solicitada

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede lograr con relaciones tipo `HasManyThrough` ([Aquí puedes ver la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)). Con la info que indicas, la cosa sería así:

En el modelo `User`, puedes usar el siguiente método:

```
public function contacts() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Contact::class, //Modelo para la tabla de contactos
        Visit::class, //Modelo para la tabla de visitantes
        'heroe_id', // Llave foránea del user de la tabla visitantes
        'destino_id', // Llave foranea del user de la tabla contactos
        'id', // Llave primaria de la tabla visitantes
        'id' // Llave primaria de la tabla contactos
    );
}
```

No tendría cómo hacer un test, pero espero que sí devuelva los datos que necesitas.

Comment: No creo que sea necesario considerar el uso de una relación *has many through* pues el OP indica que `from_id` presente en el modelo `Contacto` es el vínculo directo con el modelo `User` lo cual quiere decir que se puede establecer una consulta sin depender de un modelo intermedio